# filling a list with the indexes of an other list

Tags: python

I got two lists `list1` and `list2`, I want to get all the indexes of the of  the element of `list1` that are also in 2nd one

```
    for i in list1:
       print(i) ## this works fine 
Test_features_index.append(list1.index(i for i in list2))# here not that well
```

running this doens't work here is what I get :

```
<ipython-input-35-8d7ff70a8be0> in <module>()
----> 1 Test_features_index.append(list1.index(i for i in list2))

ValueError: <generator object <genexpr> at 0x0000021710BBA7D8> is not in list
```

Any idea how to do that? I wanted to avoid a for loop, but not sure if it's possible

Comment: You could do it with a list comprehension e.g. `Test_features_index.append([list1.index(i) for i in list2 if i in list1])` (assuming that you actually wanted to append the result to another list called `Test_features_index`). Be aware that index returns only the first index if an item occurs multiple times. `index` throws an exception if the item can't be found, requiring `if i in list1` check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to find the index of a generator expression which is supposedly in your list. Besides, using `list.index` repeatedly is not very performant since you'll be running the entire length of the list (worst case) every time.

You can instead use a *list comprehension* with [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate):

```
set2 = set(list2)
Test_features_index = [i for i, x in enumerate(list1) if x in set2]
```

Using a set for the lookup of shared items ensures 0(1) lookup time as opposed to O(n) for lists.

Comment: thanks for the help I don't get why  you're using set2 extra it did work without ;-)

Comment: @Engine It's a performance hack. Set membership lookup is faster than that for lists.